# Multicasting in C on localhost

Tags: c, networking, udp, localhost

I have the participant's and the leader's code in one file, but I distinguish them by the structure. Unfortunately, the participant is not receiving multicast messages from the server, while the leader successfully delivers them, and the server broadcasts such messages in the group. I've checked it with Wireshark. I'm counting on help in receiving these messages in the 'send.c' code (participant).

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    ssize_t n;
    int sockfd;
    int recv_s;

    struct user_account currentUser;
    struct sockaddr_in servaddr,localSock;
    struct ip_mreq mreq;
    socklen_t len = sizeof(servaddr);
    
    int roleChoice;
    char sendline[MAX_BUFF], recvline[MAX_BUFF];

    u_int yes=1;

     // user struct instance
    memset(&currentUser, 0, sizeof(currentUser));
    
    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
    if (sockfd < 0) {
        perror("Błąd w tworzeniu gniazda");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    memset(&servaddr, 0, sizeof(servaddr));
    servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    servaddr.sin_port = htons(PORT);
    if (inet_pton(AF_INET, argv[1], &servaddr.sin_addr) <= 0) {
        perror("Błąd w inet_pton");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    // mcast socket
    recv_s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
    if (recv_s < 0) {
        perror("Błąd w tworzeniu gniazda odbiorczego");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    setsockopt(recv_s, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &yes, sizeof(yes));
    fcntl(recv_s, F_SETFL, O_NONBLOCK);
    #ifdef SO_REUSEPORT
    if (setsockopt(recv_s, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEPORT, &yes, sizeof(yes)) < 0) {
        perror("setsockopt(SO_REUSEPORT) failed");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    #endif

    // preparing to receive
    memset(&localSock, 0, sizeof(localSock));
    localSock.sin_family = AF_INET;
    localSock.sin_port = htons(MULTICAST_PORT);
    localSock.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    if (bind(recv_s, (struct sockaddr*)&localSock, sizeof(localSock)) < 0) {
        perror("Błąd w bind gniazda odbiorczego multicastu");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    
    //role 
 if(currentUser.is_instructor){

           //joining the session

           //creating a session
                session_active = 1;
           
          //**
            if (session_active) {
                join_multicast_group(sockfd, MULTICAST_GROUP);
            }

            
            while (session_active) {
                char message[256];
                printf("msg to send (lub 'quit' aby wyjść): ");
                fgets(message, 256, stdin);
                message[strcspn(message, "\n")] = 0;

                if (strncmp(message, "quit", 4) == 0) {
                    break; // Wyjście z pętli
                }

                sprintf(sendline, "MULTICAST_MSG %d: %s", currentUser.training_id, message);
                sendto(sockfd, sendline, strlen(sendline), 0, (const struct sockaddr *)&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr));
                printf("Wysłano wiadomość: %s\n", message);
            }

            
            leave_multicast_group(sockfd, MULTICAST_GROUP);
        }
```

**SERVER SIDE**

```
else if(strncmp(buffer, "MULTICAST_MSG", 13) == 0) {
                    int session_id;
                    char message_content[MAX_BUFF];
                    if (sscanf(buffer, "MULTICAST_MSG %d: %[^\t\n]", &session_id, message_content) == 2) {
                        send_multicast_message(send_s, message_content, MULTICAST_GROUP, MULTICAST_PORT);
                        printf("Rozesłano wiadomość multicastową do uczestników sesji %d.\n", session_id);
                    } else {
                        printf("Niepoprawny format wiadomości multicastowej.\n");
                    }
```

```
void send_multicast_message(int send_socket, const char* message_content, const char* multicast_group, int multicast_port) {
    struct sockaddr_in multicast_addr;
    memset(&multicast_addr, 0, sizeof(multicast_addr));
    multicast_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    multicast_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(multicast_group);
    multicast_addr.sin_port = htons(multicast_port);

    if (sendto(send_socket, message_content, strlen(message_content), 0, (struct sockaddr*)&multicast_addr, sizeof(multicast_addr)) < 0) {
        perror("sendto failed");
    } else {
        printf("Rozesłano wiadomość multicastową.\n");
    }
}
```

**PARTICIPANT CODE IN THE same SEND.C FILE**

```
//joining the session
join_multicast_group(recv_s, MULTICAST_GROUP);
                printf("waiting for mcast messages...\n");
                int session_active = 1;
                while (session_active) {
                    char multicast_message[MAX_BUFF];
                    memset(multicast_message, 0, MAX_BUFF);
                    socklen_t addrlen = sizeof(localSock);
                    ssize_t multicast_len = recvfrom(recv_s, multicast_message, MAX_BUFF, 0, (struct sockaddr *)&localSock, &addrlen);
                    if (multicast_len > 0) {
                        multicast_message[multicast_len] = '\0';
                        printf("mcast msg: %s\n", multicast_message);
                    }

              
                    usleep(100000); // Sleep for 100 milliseconds
                }
                
                leave_multicast_group(recv_s, MULTICAST_GROUP);
```

```
./send (presenter)
enter message('quit' to exit) : hi!

send: hi!

./recv 
received: MULTICAST_MSG 10: hi!

sending multicast.

send mcast message to participants session no 10.

./send (participant)

u joined the session

waiting for mcast messages...
```

participant is trying to receive mcast messages from server and listen to socket but still not receiving them. any help? My mcast port and address are consistent for server and client.

additionally:

```
void send_multicast_message(int send_socket, const char* message_content, const char* multicast_group, int multicast_port) 
{ struct sockaddr_in multicast_addr; memset(&multicast_addr, 0, sizeof(multicast_addr)); multicast_addr.sin_family = AF_INET; multicast_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(multicast_group); multicast_addr.sin_port = htons(multicast_port); sendto(send_socket, message_content, strlen(message_content), 0, (struct sockaddr*)&multicast_addr, sizeof(multicast_addr)) < 0) }
```

Comment: Not seeing IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP for participant

Comment: ```void join_multicast_group(int sockfd, const char* multicast_group) {
    struct ip_mreq mreq;
    mreq.imr_multiaddr.s_addr = inet_addr(multicast_group);
    mreq.imr_interface.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);

    if (setsockopt(sockfd, IPPROTO_IP, IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP, &mreq, sizeof(mreq)) < 0) {
        perror("setsockopt(IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP) failed");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}```

Comment: A series of incomplete snippets aren't good enough.  You need to include a [mcve].

Comment: its a system.. with my native lang.. i can give the link so on.. : client https://pastebin.com/NfxQw3mz, serwer: https://pastebin.com/NPDsy8tM

Comment: @user7777777 Please add additional code to the question itself -- not in the comments section.